# Update List Widget from another class

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qlistwidget

How can I update `listWidget` from another class?

I am calling method `showMessageName()` from another class method:

```
   {
    MainWindow guiObj;     
    guiObj.showMessageName(somedata);
    }



   void MainWindow::showMessageName(QString msgName)
   {
         ui->listWidget->addItem(msgName);

         qDebug() <<"test"<< msgName;
         return ;

   }
```

This does not update my `ui` but following code does:

```
 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //ui->listWidget->addItem("asdf"); this update is fine

    }
```

I cant access `ui` in another class, so I used the aoter option but it has not updated my data.

Comment: If you update your `showMessageName` function to take a `const QString&` does that help?

Comment: I tried keeping ui->listWidget->addItem("asdf"); .. But this also doesnot show anytext on listWidget.

Comment: Also, read this link.. But now it crashes my application and UI doesnot appear..

Comment: link: http://www.qtforum.org/article/27688/accessing-ui-widgets-from-another-class.html

Comment: It looks you have created your `MainWindow` object as a local variable. It will get destroyed as soon as the method returns. Use a `MainWindow` pointer and create an object in heap using `new`

Comment: Could you connect both classes using signals? The idea is to emit a signal with the text and receive the signal in `MainWindow` to add the item in the list.